# Inconsistent ADO.NET model after editing database

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a ASP.NET MVC 4 app. I am using **Entity Framework Database First** design principle.

Initially I created the database on **MySQL** and then in visual studio i setup a connection to MySQL and generated the ADO.NET data model.
But later I added some tables in MySQL and then from Visual Studio I did this.

[image]

I can see the new entity types in the model diagram but no classes corresponding to the new entities have been generated in the Model.tt file. I mean classes from older tables are present, classes from newer tables are missing.

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Is your edmx nested in a folder? If so this might be a bug that was fixed in VS 2012 Update1 where code would not be re-generated if edmx was in a folder. Install VS 2012 Update 1 and the issue should be gone. You can also right click the edmx file and click Run Custom Tool option to enforce code generation.

Comment: i updated visual studio 2012...the changes to the table are now coming but when i add a new stored procedure and then update the ADO.NET model then **no code is generated for my stored procedure**